# Same file extension registered for different mime-types

Tags: 20.04, mime-type

I have a my file extension as .xyz and I have it registered for my mime type(ex:myMime) in the .xml file. Now I was unaware that the same extension is already been registerd for some other mime type.

But now if I check for the mime registered with the extension, it shows that my mime is registered for the extension. But I cannot identify on what basis is the mime being decided for the extension.

Should there be some warning around the extension being already registered?

Note : I m performing this file association in ubuntu 20.04, if that matters.